# SQL:- how to take Average of multiple(50) Columns with many null values in between, without listing 50 columns names in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

how to take Average of multiple(50) Columns with many null values in between, without listing 50 columns names in SQL?I need more general way of handling such situation?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Because SQL Server knows the `PIVOT` function, which MySQL doesn't

Comment: There may be answers posted that work here. But longer term, if you have multiple columns containing the "same" type of data - such that taking the average of them even makes sense - they shouldn't be in separate columns. If you can normalize your tables, future queries should also be easier to develop.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would need to transpose your current table to achieve this. As far as I know, there is no way to transpose a MySQL table without specifying the exact columns to be transposed. So I would say that the best way would be to retrieve a row (or rows, depending on your needs) with SELECT * FROM table and then calculate the average using the whatever scripting / programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
select (isnull(col1,0)+isnull(col2,0)+...+isnull(col50,0))/50 as averageval
from table
```

but it is clear that your table design is wrong.  You should have a values table that contains these values.

This is what a correct design would look like:

```
maintable
----------
id int

valuetable
----------
mainkey int -- foreign key to maintable.id
valuenum int -- may not be needed goes from 1 to 50
value int
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point you will need to list the columns.  Sql will not know which columns to include in the calculation until it is told.
If you calculation is a more then "just one time" consider placing a computed column in the table to hold the calculation which is maintained by SQL.